# Correct ~*e !clrstack Problem

Tags: visual-studio-2005, debugging

When I issued the following command from VS2005 immediate window, it failed with error message "End of expression expected". How can I correct this?

```
~*e !clrstack
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the debugging capabilities of SOS, you better use [WinDbg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDbg). It would be more comfortable to debug and issue commands than in Visual Studio.

Comment: Also, SOS is not guaranteed to work with Visual Studio, though you can sometimes get it to work in VS (lost the MS reference for this unfortunately).